# How do I get this object to join with the animation?

Tags: armature, bones

I have this figure with a sword as a separate object:
[image]

This character has a 422-frame animation, and the sword is supposed to be a part of it.  Basically, the character is supposed to take out the sword with his right hand (which means the sword springs out of nowhere around keyframe 41), twirl it around, and then carry on with his animation.  My problem is that I can't seem to get the sword to join with the animation.

The armature has a bone called bn_r_weapon, and that seems to be the bone that should be controlling the sword.  I have tried many things to get this to work.  I have added a vertex group to the sword that matches that bone's name and then tried various parenting methods.  I've tried to parent to the armature, I've tried entering Pose mode and parenting directly to that bone.  One of three things happens: 1) the mesh badly distorts, 2) the sword joins with the animation, but rotated and translated completely wrong, or 3) nothing happens at all, and the mesh stays right there on the floor while the rest of the character carries on with the animation.

Please help.  I'm completely out of ideas.  I have tried to follow advice from similar threads, but they always result in one of the three outcomes I described above.  My blend file is here:

https://www.mediafire.com/file_premium/vpsy3rl7n7ckwgm/SM_WIP.blend/file

How can I get this sword to join with the character's animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In object mode go to frame 50, move and rotate the sword until you get the desired pose, shift select the rig, go to pose mode, select the bn_r_weapon bone and press Ctrl P > Bone.

[image]

Comment: I was hunting for a procedural way to do this, but your solution really does solve the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: The file contains no clue to where the sword is supposed to be.

Comment: It's supposed to be at the same location as the bone bn_r_weapon.